# Term to Describe Strongly Clustered Data

Tags: clustering, dataset

I have some data which are strongly gathered into more than one cluster. I am looking for a term to effectively describe this phenomenon: e.g., *multi-clustered data*, which however seems to me that we have later imposed a cluster analysis to identify more than one cluster. So far I prefer *multi-polarised data*, but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: It is OK to say data consist of clusters or classes or clumps which are strongly separated. Word "cluster" does not necessarily mean that it emerged as a result of cluster analysis.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you for your answer. But to efficiently summarise this concept, don't you think that *multi-polarised data* sounds catchier? It is for a paper, so the appeal of a word shouldn't be an issue, but since it seems there isn't an established terminology, why not?

Comment: "Polarised" implies that a dimension of a space is bounded by two ("bipolar dimension") or one ("unipolar dimension") clusters. That is, `A-----B` or `A------`. If there are 3+ clusters in a line, `A--B--C`, word "polarised" looks unsuitable.

Comment: @ttnphns Are you sure of this? :o I apologise for my astonishment; I am not a native English speaker, but my mothertongue is a romance language, and for me *polarised* simply implies the existence of some concentrations, regardless of their number. ;)